# how to bind a property of a class which is in another assembly in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding

In WPF, is it possible to bind a property of class which is other assembly to the control which is in different assembly .Please help.
Thanks

Comment: do you have referenced that assembly to your project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yea, you can reference that assembly to your wpf project, than add a namespace in xaml like this

```
<UserControl xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SampleClass;assembly=SampleLibrary"...
```

than add that class to UserControl's resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <custom:SampleClass x:Key="myClass"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

than bind to it's property

```
 <TextBox Text={Binding Source={StaticResource myClass},Path=MyProperty}/>
```

Comment: you are welcome,just don't forgot to mark as answer if I answered to question